# How to submit html form to Spring Boot without using JSP?

Tags: html, spring, forms, spring-boot

Is there a way to submit a html form to Spring Boot without using JSP?  All I can find is examples using JSP.

Comment: you can use plain html or Js.

Comment: Here is an example with html: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start , https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: That example does not show how to send form data to the backend.

Comment: I found a way to do it with Ajax here:  https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ajax-example/

Comment: you can do it with ajax https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ajax-example/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is YES.

You can use normal html form tag to achieve the same.

Ultimately even jsp also renders form in plain HTML only.

If you want to verify this then load form using JSP tags and open browser element tab and you will be able to see html.

Comment: Can you point me to an example that shows how to send html form data to the Spring Boot backend without using JSP or Thymeleaf?

Comment: I think you are little confused about role of JSPs in java. The supported technologies are thymeleaf, JSP etc.